Make SCEP/NDES request with certreq
I want to make an Certreq request to my NDES service directly from the server where is running the Certificate authority and the NDES service
Knowing that
My service account is: CRYPTOTEST\testservicendes
The certificate model is: TestMobile
The FQDN of the CA is: CRYPTOTEST-MyServer-CA-1
The SCEP service URL is: http://MyServer/CertSrv/mscep
I made a private Key and then a CSR
OpenSSL> genrsa -out private-key.key 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
........................+++
..........+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
OpenSSL> req -new -key private-key.key -out CRYPTOTEST.csr
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:
Locality Name (eg, city) []:
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:
Email Address []:

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:23E4CD1A4384204E
An optional company name []:

23E4CD1A4384204E come from http://MyServer/CertSrv/mscep_admin/ "The enrollment challenge password"
Then I make this request
> certreq -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate:TestMobile" -config "http://MyServer/CertSrv/mscep/" CRYPTOTEST.csr
3001.279.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL): KeyExchangeAction: FALSE
3001.438.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
450.201.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x1 (WIN32: 1 ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION): Error
450.202.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x2710 (WIN32: 10000)
450.219.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x0 (WIN32: 0): http://MyServer/CertSrv/mscep/
450.219.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x1 (WIN32: 1 ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION): The endpoint address URL is invalid. 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
450.223.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x0 (WIN32: 0): Log
708.1578.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
708.2137.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
708.1830.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
708.2152.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
708.890.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
438.399.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
1401.5498.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL): ICertRequest::Submit
1401.5499.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
1401.5504.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL): ICertRequest::Submit
1401.6194.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
1401.19738.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:42>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
Certificate Request Processor: The endpoint address URL is invalid. 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)
449.199.0:<2024/5/2, 15:01:45>: 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)

I always get "Certificate Request Processor: The endpoint address URL is invalid. 0x803d0020 (-2143485920 WS_E_INVALID_ENDPOINT_URL)" how ever I try to change things, I keep getting this error
I don't know what I'm doing wrong could you help me please ?
